# How to verify Token created in seperate Laravel-Instance

Tags: laravel

I have an API that issues Personal-Access-Tokens. Implemented with Laravel-Passport.

I have other API's that use these Access-Tokens to query the first API.

How can I use the same Tokens for these other API's to query each other? How can these other API's verify the Token?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your Laravel projects - microservices architecture type for example you can have a centralized Authentication service running separately and each one of them will have to verify with it or ... according to [Behalf inc.](https://dev.to/behalf/authentication-authorization-in-microservices-architecture-part-i-2cn0) use a JWT token globally.

Comment: yes, I would like to have my API verify the Token with the central Auth-Server. But how? Does passport offer an endpoint to do so? Is there a middleware I can use in these other API's? Do you have a code-snippet or a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: the central auth-server is actually called a [Gateway](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-does-an-api-gateway-do) which sits between your services and the client, you can use one that [amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) has or create your own which has it's downsides i found an [article](https://medium.com/@poweredlocal/developing-a-simple-api-gateway-in-php-and-lumen-f84756cce043) that talks about how to do it in Lumen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a central database for both systems for auth credentials. as we know laravel passport comes with its own migration. So both of the systems will communicate to the central auth DB for generating tokens. And both of the systems will need to have the same env variables as per the passport's requirement. and you will have to manage some CORS policy as well. Then it should work.

You can also centralize your env for auth via any remote .env file. eg: in a private s3 bucket.

Comment: that would work if they are all hosted on the same server. Sadly I can not make that decision at this point. Also there is a lot of databases involved which would mean that I have to connect all of the sercices to two databases.